# Trying to write a script to find 0kb files, and overwrite them with files from a different drive on the same path - Powershell

Tags: powershell, copy

I am very new to powershell and trying to write a script that can read all 0kb files in a folder, organize them into a list, and then determine where the same files would be on a different backup drive so that they can be replaced.

I have some code that puts it into a list and then attempts to modify the list so that it pulls from the correct drive, however, I cannot get down the file replacement.

An example of what I want this to do is this:

1. There is a file at C:\Test\test.txt that is 0kb, empty.
2. The script reads that this file is empty and writes it to a text document C:\Test2\test2.txt
3. The text document is edited so that the text is not "C:\Test\test.txt" 0 but rather H:\Test\test.txt
4. I want to then pull that specific line out of the text document and use it as a file path for a replace action with the original C:\Test\test.txt file

The reason I am trying to do this is a backup/restore gone wrong, some of the files were restored as empty when they have content on the backup drive, unfortunately there are too may to go through and one by one copy/paste the files and since the restore, some files have been significantly edited so I cannot just overwrite everything.

I have the text documents all ready to go and they are being modified as I would like, however, I cannot seem to pull the file paths correctly; nor can I seem to replace the file on the C drive, with a file on the H drive.

Code as follows:

```
    #Determines if a file is empty and writes to txt doc

forfiles /S /P c:\test /M *.* /C "cmd /c If @fsize==0 Echo @path @fsize" | Out-File C:\test\TestoutPreRename.txt

#Replaces "C:" with "H:",""" with "", and "0" with ""
$InFile = 'C:\test\TestoutPreRename.txt'
$OutFile = 'C:\test\TestoutPostRename.txt'

filter replace-chars { $_ -replace 'C:','H:' }

if (test-path $OutFile)
 { Clear-Content $OutFile }

Get-Content $InFile -ReadCount 0 | 
replace-chars  | 
Add-Content $OutFile


filter replace-chars { $_ -replace '"','' }

if (test-path $OutFile)
 { Clear-Content $OutFile }

Get-Content $OutFile -ReadCount 0 | 
replace-chars  | 
Add-Content $OutFile


filter replace-chars { $_ -replace '0','' }

if (test-path $OutFile)
 { Clear-Content $OutFile }

Get-Content $OutFile -ReadCount 0 | 
replace-chars  | 
Add-Content $OutFile

#This should determine the file path and perform the copy action while removing preexsting files with the same name in the destination
#This is where I am having issues

foreach($line in Get-Content C:\test\TestoutPostRename.txt) {
    if($line -match $regex){
    If (test-path $line) {Remove-Item $line}
    [System.IO.File]::Copy($line);

    }
}
```

I know its not clean nor good, but its the best I've got so far, any critiques are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. It's worth reading up on these Cmdlets as they may provide additional properties/parameters that you might find helpful

- [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6)
- [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6)
- [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6)
- [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6)
- [Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6)

---

```
$Path  = "C:\Test"

# Get the files. The Length property represents size - you what files where this is 0
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Length -eq 0}

# Export some of the details of the file to a CSV and/or file.
# FullName is the full path of the file
$files | Select-Object FullName,Length | Export-Csv FilesWith0kb.csv -NoTypeInformation
$files | Out-File FilesWith0kb.txt

# Loop over the list, replacing the drive C with H
# Using Copy-Item with -Force will overwrite the files if they already exist
foreach($file in $files){
    $backupFile = ($file.FullName).Replace("C:","H:")
    Copy-Item -Path $backupFile -Destination $file.FullName -Force
}
```

Comment: This is much appreciated, I have not yet had a chance to test it our really even read up on the things you posted. Just wanted to say thanks! Ill comment again once I get a grasp on what you said.